# Obtain particular node tag value from XML with batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have an XML file like this one:

```
<config>
    <intensity>0</intensity>
    <variables>
        <variable>
            <name>TONE</name>
            <value>3</value>
            <type>UNSIGNED8</type>
        </variable>
        <variable>
            <name>V_SIC</name>
            <value>0</value>
            <type>UNSIGNED8</type>
        </variable>
        <variable>
            <name>H_YPE</name>
            <value>9000</value>
            <type>INTEGER16</type>
        </variable>
        <variable>
            <name>NUM_SIC</name>
            <value>0</value>
            <type>UNSIGNED8</type>
        </variable>
    </variables>
</config>
```

I'm trying to get the value text from the node with the name `H_YPE` into a variable, so in this example, the variable should have `9000`. If the node `H_YPE` is not on the XML, simply store a 1.

I saw [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718281/parsing-a-xml-file-using-batch-to-get-values-from-some-specific-nodes) and tried what `Magoo` implements, and while I can see that the values are being parsed, I'm interested in obtaining just the one value and storing it in a variable for later use.

Apparently I'm not very savvy with batch scripts, so any and all help with this would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider install an `XPath` parser, which you can launch in commandline?

Comment: @Dominique The environment in which this is running is severely secured and I doubt that anything other than native can be installed. I'm sure that it's up to date though, so if there's anything in latest releases that comes as part of the native system it could be used.

Comment: Don't use a batch file for XML processing! Use a language with native support of XML, like PowerShell, for instance…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch file processed by the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` is the worst choice for processing an XML file because there is no built-in support for real XML processing.

The following batch file code could be used if the XML file is always structured as shown in the question.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Value=1"
if not exist "File.xml" goto ProcessValue
set "NameTagFound="
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=<>" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "<name>H_YPE</name> <value>[0123456789]*</value>" "File.xml"') do (
    if "%%I" == "name" (
        if /I "%%J" == "H_YPE" set "NameTagFound=1"
    ) else if defined NameTagFound (
        if "%%I" == "value" (
            if not "%%J" == "" set "Value=%%J"
            goto ProcessValue
        )
    )
)
:ProcessValue
echo Value is: %Value%
endlocal
```

Please note following requirements for the structure of the data in the XML file:

1. There must be leading spaces/tabs left to the start tags `<name>` and `<value>` because of `tokens=2,3 delims=<>` and the two elements must be on separate lines not containing any other element or attributes.
2. An element `name` with value `H_YPE` must exist only within element `variable` and not within another element because of the code does not check where `<name>H_YPE</name>` is found in the file.
3. The element `name` with value `H_YPE` must be inside the element `variable` on a separate line above the line with the element `value`. So the order of the elements `name` and `value` cannot be changed without adapting the code.
4. The element `variable` with the element `name` with value `H_YPE` must have also the element `value` or the value of next element `value` found anywhere below the line with `<name>H_YPE</name>` is assigned wrongly to the environment variable `Value` instead of using the default value `1`.
5. The value `H_YPE` must be always in the XML file with this spelling (all letters in upper case).

The code could be enhanced to do more XML structure checks if one of the five requirements is not always fulfilled by the XML file contents.

XML tags are case-sensitive according to XML specification. Therefore this code runs **FINDSTR** also case-sensitive although the value `H_YPE` could be in any case per XML specification. The **IF** conditions comparing strings are also case-sensitive for the same reason including the **IF** condition which checks for value `H_YPE`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`